# Declaring a multidimensional object

Tags: typescript

I have the following object structure

Variable name : metrics

Structure: metrics[period][view]

Where period is string, view is string, and metrics[period][view] will have type of Item[][];

I tried declaring as

```
metrics: {
    [period:string] : {
      [view:string] : Item[][]
    }
} = [];
```

But I got the following error:

```
Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '{ [period: string]: { [view: string]: Item[][]; }; }'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'never[]'.ts(2322)
```

How do I correctly declare the object type?

Comment: you are trying to declare object of type { [period: string]: { [view: string]: Item[][]; }; } as empty array

Answer (score 0):

An index signature is a parameter that must be of type string or number in a TypeScript interface. We can use it to denote the properties of a dynamic object. For example, we can use it like we do in the following code:

```
interface IMetric<T> {
  [peroid: string]: {
    [view: string]: T;
  };
}
```

> We have an index signature called the period and the view which is a string. The type of the dynamic member `['view': string]` is denoted by T, which is a generic type marker. This means that we can pass in any data type into it.

Then, you can declare your object like the following code:

```
const metrics: IMetric<Item[][]> = {
  period: {
    view: [[], []]
  }
};
```

So,

`console.log(metrics.period.view)` Or `console.log(metrics['period']['view'])`.